# DataTables / Checkboxes Plugin - How to return the amount of checkboxes checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables, onchange

I have a standard DataTable with checkboxes and I cannot figure out how to count the amount of checkboxed that at checked through the entire dataset on change.

*Library: https://datatables.net/*

*Plugin: https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/*

**HTML:**

```
<table id="myTable" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>01</td>
            <td>Alpha</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>02</td>
            <td>Bravo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>03</td>
            <td>Charlie</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>04</td>
            <td>Delta</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>05</td>
            <td>Echo</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
resultsTable = $("#myTable").DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets" : 0,
            "checkboxes": true,
            "orderable": false
        }
    ],
    "select": {
        "style": "multi"
    },
    "order": [[3, 'asc']]
});
```

The table renders fine, with the checkboxes in the tbody and thead. I can write simple onChange function outside of the DataTable init, but it only detects the checkboxes checked or not checked on the visible page of the table.

```
resultsTable.on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(e){
    var numChecked = $("#results-table").find("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    console.log(numChecked);
});
```

How or WHERE can I write a function that will trigger when a checkbox is changed, and then return the amount of TOTAL checkboxes in the table that are checked?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anywhere, I reckon. As long as you register event on your checkbox selector (click, change, etc)

JS:

```
var selectedBoxes = []

$('body').on('click', "#results-table input[type='checkbox']", function(e) {
  if(e.target.checked){
    // add `e.target.value` to selectedBoxes
  }
  return selectedBoxes.length;
})
```

Since datatables page change does not refresh the page - `selectedBoxes` array should store its state when you switch datatable pages.
Would something like the above satisfy your needs? Apologies if my JS skills are a bit rusty and code is not up to scratch from the style point of view :)

Comment: There has to be some callback in the DataTables/Checkboxes API that allows to check if any/all checkboxes are checked. I'm just having issues nailing it down.

Comment: Is the callback in the DataTables/Checkboxes API that allows to check if any/all checkboxes are checked found yet?